# Apache and NodeJS on the same server. Can they talk to each other?

Tags: php, node.js, apache

I've got Apache (running PHP and serving static content) and NodeJS (for websockets) running on the same server under the same domain (different ports).  I'm not using nginx.  I've already got the webclient communicating to both successfully, but now I want to close the communication loop and have Apache and NodeJS talk to each other.

It makes sense that they should be able to talk to each other, but I'm not entirely sure the best way to make it happen.  What methods are there, and which way do you suggest?

Comment: Are you referring to communicating with the literal Apache server or do you mean communicating with a specific web site / application / php script / mysql database or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the communication of the app running on apache and node app, yes it is possible. You just have to write the interfaces of your applications as services, then you can just use standard HTTP methods for communication.

Comment: I thought about that.  I don't know why, but I was hoping there was another way.  I guess it makes sense, though, that two webservers communicate via an HTTP interface.  :)  Thanks for confirming that.